# Explanation of PowerShell for IIS?

Tags: powershell, iis

I was needing to create a PowerShell script relating to IIS processes and I am new to PowerShell. I have looked at a lot of examples online and kind of get the gist of it, but I just wanted to know, how are we supposed to know all the syntax of the fields in IIS?

Such as for example I see $ApplicationPoolStatus, $ApplicationPoolName, $StartedPools, $StoppedPools, etc a lot in the scripts.

Are we just supposed to know these, or is there somewhere we can find these fields at?

Hopefully this question made sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with IIS and how it relates to Powershell. However, having a `$` in front of a name usually indicates a variable. Without being able to see a script that uses the above variable names it would be hard to say exactly what they are, and what they are doing.

Here is a link to several of the IIS Powershell Cmdlets [Technet ISS Powershell Cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)